# How do I make deduped array from object property?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I am looking for a way to loop over an array of objects and make a new array from the contents of an object property.  See the array below. I want to make an array called topics (with no duplicates) from each of the topic properties on each object.

```js
const data = [
  {
    topics [
      "tutorial",
      "JS",
      "Video"
    ],
    ...
  },
  {
    topics [
      "tutorial",
      "CSS",
      "Testing"
    ],
    ...
  },
  {
    topics [
      "HTML",
      "JS",
      "Music"
    ],
    ...
  }
]
```

I was thinking of:

```
let topics = []

data.forEach((item) => {
  topics.push(item.topics, ...topics)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `flatMap` method to `flat` the topics together, and with `new Set(Array)` you will get the unique values.

```js
const data = [
  {
    topics:  [
      "tutorial",
      "JS",
      "Video"
    ],
  },
  {
    topics: [
      "tutorial",
      "CSS",
      "Testing"
    ],
  },
  {
    topics: [
      "HTML",
      "JS",
      "Music"
    ],
  }
]

const topics = new Set(data.flatMap(item => item.topics))

console.log(Array.from(topics))
```

Comment: Thank you for the fastest ever response!! 